# Inserting external data in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have to import some data in my database . And there are some record already exist in table, not all. So what I want to do that:

1. Run a php script for inserting data in table from input array
2. Make data_id unique ( not primary key) in mysql table
3. While inserting via php script if same data_id exist don't stop the execution but skip that record and process next.

something like this I want to do.

But my script stopping execution when data_id is repeated.

can anyone explain how can i handle this.

I don't want to apply check in database that id data_id is already exist then skip that record else insert because that will make page very slow.

Comment: Well, this is a contradiction that will be hard to resolve. You would have to either make data_id not unique, or fix the data - I don't think there's any other way

Comment: If not unique then i have to apply check in whole table if that already exist. That will make page slow

Comment: I see. `INSERT IGNORE` might help as @predrag suggests - it will be easy to transform the SQL statements accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE`

Check this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

[On duplicate key ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366813/on-duplicate-key-ignore)

["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: Correct, you answered before me, +10.

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert ignore into table (fields) values (values)`

This works