# MySQL Alternative to "Lock Table" in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, table-lock

I have a requirement to insert a row into a table if a row does not already exist, and I need to do this using a stored procedure. I therefore need to select to check if the row already exists, followed by an insert. What I want to avoid is a race condition where 2 callers of the stored procedure may see that the row doesn't exist and then both try to insert the row.

My first thoughts on solving this would be to lock the table, but unfortunately you cannot issue `LOCK TABLE` in a stored procedure.

I want to avoid trapping a duplicate key insertion exception at the client (C#).

Any way of locking the table or alternative solutions?

Comment: what about insert into ... on duplicate key ...

Comment: @Haim Works great. I set a field to the same value in "on duplicate key update" and this prevents the duplicate key error and also does not update my ts field. Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
insert into ... on duplicate key
```

look on example @thummper answer:

[On duplicate key ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366813/on-duplicate-key-ignore)

Comment: +1 Works great. I set a field to the same value in "on duplicate key update" and this prevents the duplicate key error and also does not update my ts field.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

and as long as you have a unique key that would be violated by this insert happening twice, it won't be done a second time.