# How to check if MongoDB connection is alive in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app with MongoDB as backend. When the app is started, I set up the connection and use it later on requests.

But if in the mean time my db conncetion fails (ie. mongod crashes), how can I check that on the request time?

To clarify a bit:

- currently I have an "api.js", which does `db.once('open', function../* setup */)`
- on request, I do `db.find(conditions, function(err, res) { if (err) ...else ...})`.

What I want to do is check if the connection is alive before the `db.find()` clause. So if it is down, I can try to restart the db connection.

P.S. I know, I should probably set some sort of a connection pool or similar instead of keeping the connection alive all the time, but right now it's set as it is.

Comment: Ok, assuming the fastest way to -detect- an error in connection state would be to first attempt the operation and retry failure (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936922/is-inserting-a-new-database-entry-faster-than-checking-if-the-entry-exists-first) what would be the most elegant way to encapsulate that retry, do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use event to handle it as callback.
And maybe have your global variable that will identify that it is not connected.

You can have separate `db.js` file, that will behave as module. And you can have function to get collection from it.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var client;
var collections = { };

new mongodb.Db( ... ).open((function (err, c) {
  if (!err) {
    client = c;
    client.on('close', function() {
      client = null; // clear client
      collections = { }; // clear old collections
      // connection closed
    });
  } else {
    // error connecting
  }
});

// get collection
exports.get = function(name, callback) {
  if (client) {
    if (!collections[name]) {
      collections[name] = new mongodb.Collection(client, name);
    }
    callback(null, collections[name]);
  } else {
    // can perform reconnecting and then get collection and call callback
    callback(new Error('not connected'));
  }
}
```

So to use it:

```
var db = require('./db.js');

db.get('users', function(err, collection) {
  if (!err) {
    collection.find({ ...
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Sorry, just noticed you are using Mongoose, which can be different slightly.

Comment: That's what I do currently - I do, ie. users.find({}, function(err, res) { if (err).... else ...});. I wonder if there is a way to test the connection before sending a request so that I first try to restore the connection.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question at all. You get an error. That error could've been for a number of things, not all involving the connection.