# How to properly close the database connection in a lambda function?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In my lambda function, I tried to close the mongo connection as soon as I send a callback. But it has a problem.

- When I send a request, the function performs its duties, send the callback and close the database connection.
- When the second request is sent, the function times out.
- When I remove the `db.close()` things work perfectly.

I think lambda re-use the connection for all the functions because I open the connection in the top of the handler:

```js
// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

const handleCreateUser = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const { user, userProfile } = data;

  await createUser({ callback, user, userProfile });
};
```

Any idea what how to fix this? Do we really have to close the connection at this point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either move the `mongoose.connect` code inside the handler, or stop calling `db.close()`. You currently have a single database connection being reused by multiple invocations of your Lambda function, but you are closing it after the first invocation completes.

Comment: Yes my current solution is removing db.close(). But is it ok to keep it like that? Any down sides?

Comment: The downside is that the database will have to close connections itself after some timeout period.

Comment: Ah. Then will there be a way to see whether it's closed or not and re-open? I think the same issue will arise if the connection gets closed by the db.

Comment: Your DB probably won't close it faster than your Lambda function container would be destroyed due to inactivity, but I'd look at this if you want to add a check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786080/how-to-check-if-mongodb-connection-is-alive-in-node-js

Comment: If it is moved to handleCreateUser function, will it leave an open db connection after each lambda invocation. Suppose cloud watch triggers this lambda function every 1 minute after 1 hour , will there be 60 open db connections ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264495/nestjs-aws-lambda-sequelize-connection-pool

Comment: @UJIndia yes that is correct

Answer (score 3):

Lambda will executes your handleCreateUser function in each invocation but everything outside handleCreateUser will be executed only on cold start. Lambda will cache that values for further invocations and will not execute

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

in every invocation. So i think you should move this code in handleCreateUser function.

Comment: If it is moved to handleCreateUser function, will it leave an open db connection after each lambda invocation. Suppose cloud watch triggers this lambda function every 1 minute after 1 hour , will there be 60  open db connections ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264495/nestjs-aws-lambda-sequelize-connection-pool

Comment: If it is moved in handleCreateUser function, It will create new connection for each execution. Now for your question, If you have created connection in handleCreateUser function you can close that connection at the end of the function. This way no connection will left open after completion of AWS lambda execution.

Answer (score 1):

My usage is Python but you will do this in your preferred language. Best solution for lambda, considering pay per time:
Run this globally before lamba function (i do it in a config class)

```
if self.conn == None or self.conn.close == 1:
  self.make_connection()
```

Up to you how you implement make_connection().
Do not use db.close() at all.

AWS calls loads your lambda function and runs you global functions once.
After that at every call it ONLY RUNS the lambda which it keeps loaded for a while (from some tests 20min to 50min).
The connection will be closed by the db driver on an internal timeout.

Advantages -you only open connection once in a long time saving you time for every lambda run.

Disadvantages - you hold on connection all the time lambda is in memory.

In my opinion it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the DB connection outside your handler, it will be setup in the [`Init` phase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html#runtimes-lifecycle) of the Lambda container. Then it can be used by one or more invocations ([`Invoke` phase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html#runtimes-lifecycle)). So closing the connection inside your handler will result in the following invocations having a non-usable, closed connection.

To properly close your connection (rather than awaiting the timeout), you can use a hook that triggers on container shutdown. As copied from [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/graceful-shutdown-with-aws-lambda):

```
// SIGTERM Handler 
process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
    console.info('[runtime] SIGTERM received');

    console.info('[runtime] cleaning up');
    // perform actual clean up work here. 
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    
    console.info('[runtime] exiting');
    process.exit(0)
});
```