# MySQL multiple insert when duplicates not allowed.

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have a table with 3 columns.  Each has a unique index.

I'd like to do multiple inserts at once (300 records a pop). When a duplicate entry occurs it cancels the insert in its entirety. This means if 1 out of the 300 is a duplicate, none of them will be inserted.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing your query from `INSERT INTO ...` to `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`. This will cause any errors to become warnings, and your other records should be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If your inserts are idempotent, `update or replace` would help you out.

Given they are likely not, there isn't any super-efficient way to do this without something falling back to inserting individual rows as a fallback - to isolate the problem row.

If you are batching inserts to reduce latency from client to server, consider using a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html) to take the rows, and does insert on the server side taking all the data in a shot; that can have a fallback that does appropriate error handling on a row-by-row basis.

That assumes, of course, that there is some meaningful error handling that can be done on the server side without needing synchronous communication to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transaction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

`START TRANSACTION`
`// DO QUERIES`
`COMMIT`

If anything goes wrong in DO QUERIES, none of the records will be committed.

If you want to ignore errors. use --force from your mysql command line

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite.... he's doing a multiple insert and the entire insert statement is dying due to a bad record.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
  INSERT INTO table (username, id)
          VALUES
          ('john', 1),
          ('jim', 2),
          ('mary', 3),
          ('jack', 4),
          ('helen', 4) ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

If you want the entry to be replaced , use UPDATE instead of IGNORE.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE`. It only supports `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: There is `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366813/on-duplicate-key-ignore and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update for more info