# Jooq - Ignore Duplicates

Tags: java, sql, database, jooq

I'm currently using Jooq for a project, but I need a way to ignore duplicate keys on insert.

I've got an array of objects I want to write into a table but if they already exist determined by a composite unique index on START_TS and EVENT_TYPE I want the insert to silently fail.

My Code looks something like this:

```
InsertValuesStep<MyRecord> query = fac.insertInto(MY_REC,
                MY_REC.START_TS,
                MY_REC.STOP_TS,
                MY_REC.EVENT_DATA,
                MY_REC.EVENT_TYPE,
                MY_REC.PUBLISHED_TS,
                MY_REC.MY_ID
                );

        for(int i=0;i<recs.length;i++)
        {
            MyClass evt = recs[i]; 
            query.values(
                    new java.sql.Date(evt.startTS.getTime()),
                    (evt.stopTS == null) ? null : new java.sql.Date(evt.stopTS.getTime()),
                    evt.eventData,
                    evt.type.name(),
                    date,
                    id)

        }

        query.execute();
```

A solution like this would be ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920619/416338

I figure I need to add something like:

```
.onDuplicateKeyUpdate().set(MY_REC.EVENT_TYPE,MY_REC.EVENT_TYPE);
```

But whatever I add it still seems to throw an error on duplicates.

Comment: I don't know this tool, but in plain SQL you can do something like `INSERT INTO table (SELECT col1, col2 FROM (VALUES(val1, val2)) as temp(col1, col2) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM table where col1 = val1))` which has the virtue of working for pretty much every RDBMS (or a slight variation).

Comment: @LukasEder `INSERT INTO t (column1, ... columnN) SELECT ... FROM some other tables ...` is supported by almost all (if not all) DBMS.

Comment: @ypercube: I must've missed the `SELECT`... my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for MySQL's [`INSERT IGNORE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax is on the roadmap for [jOOQ 2.3.0](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/ticket/1295). This had been discussed recently on the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jooq-user/LvfNGIKpvn8/discussion). This syntax will be simulated in all other SQL dialects that support the SQL `MERGE` statement.

In the mean time, as a workaround, you could try to insert one record at a time