# Array Comparison and inserting unique value in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I Have an array with all the id's in my MySQL DB. In second array,  have ID's which I need to insert into the same table. I need to check if the Id's which I am going to insert are present in first array or not and then insert it into the DB.

Help me out in finding the unique values.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: why don't you refer php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_intersect() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find out whether two arrays satisfy your conditions and then make a decision whether data can be inserted to DB

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are PKs, you can use insert on duplicate update (here is a stack question that might help you; unrelated, but for syntax) [On duplicate key ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366813/on-duplicate-key-ignore).