# magento SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '606078' for key 'PRIMARY

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am working on a live site http://spectnlens.com/.
so when I tack backup and unzip files on my localhost i get one error

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '606078' for key 'PRIMARY'

Trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110):     Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Resource\Visitor.php(174): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor_inf...', Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Resource\Visitor.php(108): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(463): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Visitor.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(408): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#18 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176):    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 D:\xampp\htdocs\spect\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Error log record number: 1097527033

I dont know whats going on please help me database is uploaded and admin is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the visitors log first
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning

Or if you are Importing , It looks like you are trying to import data to an existing database and some record(s) already exist, you can either drop the entire database and import to empty or follow one of the option shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366813/on-duplicate-key-ignore) when importing your sql file. Note that if you are the one doing the export, you have the options to have this statements already included by selecting either Drop if Exist or INSERT IGNORE